# Open a custom file or attachment in a suported app

Tags: ios, file, swiftui

I have a SwiftUI app that supports the FASTA file format, and I want to open the app from mail attachments or from Files. The SwiftUI apps not a Document app, just the results kind.

I have added a Document Type, imported and exported type identifiers, and made some code changes as below.

But still my app won't open. What else do I need to do for this to work in a SwiftUI app?

```xml
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeIconSystemGenerated</key>
        <integer>1</integer>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>FASTA</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Viewer</string>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Owner</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>com.xyz/formats/fasta</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>

<key>UTImportedTypeDeclarations</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>UTTypeConformsTo</key>
            <array>
                <string>public.data</string>
            </array>
            <key>UTTypeDescription</key>
            <string>FASTA File</string>
            <key>UTTypeIcons</key>
            <dict>
                <key>UTTypeIconText</key>
                <string>FASTA</string>
            </dict>
            <key>UTTypeIdentifier</key>
            <string>com.xyz/formats/fasta</string>
            <key>UTTypeTagSpecification</key>
            <dict>
                <key>public.filename-extension</key>
                <array>
                    <string>fasta</string>
                </array>
            </dict>
            <key>public.filename-extension</key>
            <array>
                <string>fasta</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
```

```swift
var body: some Scene {

    WindowGroup {
        ContentView()
            .onOpenURL(perform: { url in
                print(url)
            })
    }
    .handlesExternalEvents(matching: [])
}
```

This is based on https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Articles/RegisteringtheFileTypesYourAppSupports.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010411-SW1

Comment: Replace the `/` characters with `.`. Also, if you choose to share such a file from some other app, such as an email attachment, is your app listed as an option for opening the file?

Comment: I've done that @HangarRash. My intention was to achieve opening this from Files and Mail, and I thought this would so it. How do I achieve this?

Comment: Also, @HangarRash do you want to reply as a question so I can give you credit for time - presuming this solves my issue :)

Comment: You didn't answer my 2nd question in my first comment. When you try to share a such a file from Mail or Files, is your app listed as one of the selectable apps that you can send the file to?

Comment: @HangarRash "Is your app listed as an option for opening the file?" No it's not. I thought these plist changes would achieve this. I basically want to achieve "Open in" for this file type so I can open from Mail and Files.

Answer (score 1):

Value `xyz/formats/fasta` in `LSItemContentTypes`  seems incorrect. You need to specify Uniform Type Identifier there. Try to use `com.mysite.fasta` first.

Also I see a space in `UTTypeIdentifier` value which is also an issue.

Comment: Sorry, the space is a typo from editing on my phone and the xyz was just to obscure my bundle details. The issue remains.